# published on behalf of the users of my application

Tags: php, facebook, cron, facebook-wall

I need to publish on behalf of my facebook users, such that at 3 in the afternoon one of my random users post on their wall, "Hello, it's 3 pm"

is this possible?

Comment: Is this an attempt at a spam bot?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. The only thing you need is to retrieve [publish_stream](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) permission

Comment: tengo los permisos y lo que hago para publicar ahora es eso 

$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', array('message' => "$mensaje"));

public but only when a user enters the app, as I do to make it without the user is connected, as I d and the user id which has to publish?

Comment: @Sebs Lakes Phillips: you can specify `user_id` instead of `me`